# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DATABASE": syntax error....there is error when i try to connect sql3 to python

Tags: python, sqlite, connector

There seems to be an error while trying to execute the below block of code:-

```
 import sqlite3

 connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

 cursor = connection.cursor()

 sql_file = open(r"C:\Users\ANTHONY\Desktop\CSV&XLSX\mysqlsampledatabase.sql")
 sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
 cursor.executescript(sql_as_string)

 for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customer"):
     print(row)
```

this is the output:-

> OUTPUT: File "c:/Users/ANTHONY/Downloads/reg/regression.py", line 9, in 
> cursor.executescript(sql_as_string)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "DATABASE": syntax error

Comment: The error is in your SQL file.

Comment: Klaus is right.  Your script implies that you are trying to use an SQL script from a Mysql example.  Mysql supports many SQL features that sqlite3 does not.  Show is the SQL.

Comment: OH thanks guys... so you suggest me taking up another SQL file?